# Android programmatically tile image as background

Tags: android, image, background

I have an image that I want to tile horizontally and I need it done programmatically.  I have tried two ways, and both do not work.

button_inner_shadow is the image
navigation_background is the xml that suppose to tile the above image

1: tile image directly

```
BitmapDrawable navigationBackground = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.button_inner_shadow));
navigationBackground.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
navigationTextViews[id].setBackgroundDrawable(navigationBackground);
```

2: use xml to tile image

```
navigationBackground = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.navigation_background));
navigationTextViews[id].setBackgroundDrawable(navigationBackground);
```

navigation_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:src="@drawable/button_inner_shadow"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

I also use `setBackgroundResource` to set change the background color in another part of the program and thought that was a problem. I have added `navigationTextViews[id].setBackgroundResource(0);`, which should remove the background resource, and that doesn't work with the above solutions I used.

EDIT: navigationTextViews[] is an array of TextViews

Comment: what error did you get, post logcat?

Answer (score 4):

Well, for some reason, the first option worked with a different image, so I am guessing the problem is that my first image (which is a gradient with some transparency) was too transparent.